# Finding the index for which a certain of element of an array exists in another array for last time

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '5', '6']
operatorsValue = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%']
operatorPosition = arr.findIndex((x) => operatorsValue.includes(x));
```

Using operatorPosition I can find the index of '+' but i want to find the operator of '*' in the arr.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in `findLastIndex` method on arrays. Just loop backward through the array looking for a match:

```
let operatorPosition;
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (operatorsValue.includes(arr[i])) {
        operatorPosition = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to create an object with the indexes of all the operators in the array.

```js
let oprObject = operatorsValue.reduce((acc, opr) => {
  acc[opr] = arr.indexOf(opr)
  return acc
}, {})
```

**Demo:**

```js
arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '5', '6']
operatorsValue = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%']

let oprObject = operatorsValue.reduce((acc, opr) => {
  acc[opr] = arr.indexOf(opr)
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(oprObject)
console.log("+ is at index:", oprObject["+"])
console.log("* is at index:", oprObject["*"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute the last index for each operator and take the max of them:

```js
arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '5', '6']
operatorsValue = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%']
lastOperatorPosition = Math.max(...operatorsValue.map(op => arr.lastIndexOf(op)))

console.log(lastOperatorPosition)
```